# Software for composing iPhone game background music

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I want to compose some basic background music for an iPhone game.  What's a good program for OS X (10.5.8)?  I'd like to save the audio files in a compressed format that's compatible w/ AVAudioPlayer (aif, aiff, caf, mp3, aac, m4a, mp4, wav).

Perhaps something like Logic Studio Express?

Cheers!

Comment: This is more of a question about software, not programming, so I'd say that it is more appropriate for Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic Studio Express is definitely a good option. It is loaded with features, and actually developed by Apple IIRC. 
You could also try [Reason](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/), if that is the sort of thing you are looking for.